# Gerar Chave NFe

Tags: algoritmo, nfe

Tenho um software de código fechado que valida a chave NFe na entrada da nota fiscal pelo módulo de estoque.

Preciso gerar algumas chaves NFe para testes.

Até o momento sei que a chave NFe valida o código IBGE do fornecedor, número do documento, e Serie da Nota.

Alguém tem o algorítimo para geração dessas chaves de notas fiscais?

Preciso do algoritmo para fazer um sistema de geração dessas chaves.

Procurei na internet mas não achei essa informação, talvez esteja procurando errado.

Podem me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A chave da NFe possui a seguinte regra:

```
   cUF - Código da UF do emitente do Documento Fiscal;
    AAMM - Ano e Mês de emissão da NF-e;
    CNPJ - CNPJ do emitente;
    mod - Modelo do Documento Fiscal;
    serie - Série do Documento Fiscal;
    nNF - Número do Documento Fiscal;
    tpEmis – forma de emissão da NF-e;
    cNF - Código Numérico que compõe a Chave de Acesso;
    cDV - Dígito Verificador da Chave de Acesso.
```

Com estrutura da tabela a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: http://www.oobj.com.br/bc/article/como-%C3%A9-formada-a-chave-de-acesso-de-uma-nf-e-nfc-e-de-um-ct-e-e-um-mdf-e-281.html

Manual Nfe: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=9hd38oni4Nc=

Comment: Perfeito, @AnthraxisBR!
Eu só vou sugerir também que dê uma olhada no Projeto ACBr, que sempre recomendo quando tratam de qualquer assunto relacionado a software comercial. Eles tem exemplos interessantes que podem ser úteis :)

Comment: Ajudou bastante, vou tentar gerar as chaves com as informações desse manual.

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/adeniltonbs/Zeus.Net.NFe.NFCe

classe do repositório que gera a chave, valida chave e gera ela: https://github.com/adeniltonbs/Zeus.Net.NFe.NFCe/blob/40dced57b746ef6da5bb2e8a58b9b18129cefaea/DFe.Utils/ChaveFiscal.cs

Este repositório gera a chave para você, transmite, gera o xml.